# ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

Hello I'm a beginner in computer I'm trying to migrate an application on a server jboss here is the error he refers me:

```
> 10:11:50,027 ERROR
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/@CONTEXT_ROOT@]]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) JBWEB000289: Servlet action threw
> load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack from [Module
> "deployment.MYAPPS_DIM_EAR.ear.commons-digester.jar:main" from Service
> Module Loader]    at
> org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Digester.java:185)
> [commons-digester.jar:"1.5"]  at
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initServlet(ActionServlet.java:1405)
> [struts.jar:1.1]  at
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:466)
> [struts.jar:1.1]  at
> javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
> [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1112)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.13.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.13.Final-redhat-2]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]    at
> org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
> 
> 10:11:50,040 ERROR
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/@CONTEXT_ROOT@]]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) JBWEB000289: Servlet ApplicationInit
> threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap from [Module
> "deployment.MYAPPS_DIM_EAR.ear.commons-beanutils.jar:main" from
> Service Module Loader]    at
> org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
> [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]  at
> javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
> [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1112)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802)
> [jbossweb-7.5.20.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.20.Final-redhat-1]    at
> org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.13.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.13.Final-redhat-2]    at
> org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.13.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.13.Final-redhat-2]    at
> org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.13.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.13.Final-redhat-2]    at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Hi [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Does your package include the apache commons collections library? Maybe your previous application server provided it. Depending on your JBoss version (JBoss what by the way? JBoss AS? JBoss EAP ?) it may also be included as a global module toward which you could declare a dependance.

Comment: the application was on a server webSphere,now i want to migrate him in JBoss EAP 6.4

Comment: @Pedro did you try the solution I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference commons collections module from your application.
Please include a MANIFEST file with the following data.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.commons.collections
```